# What is the source 0x and Destination 0x in the following header

Tags: tcp

[Source and Destination Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itGwm.jpg)

45 20 00 28 dd 91 00 00 79 06 f4 38 ac d9 02 0a c0 a8 00 5a

I believe it is:

Source 0x: c0 a8 00 5a
Destination 0x: ac do 02 0a

I just need confirmation or correction if I am wrong.

Comment: Is this the actual TCP header, or from the IP header? Do you know the structures of the IP and TCP headers?

Comment: I inserted a screenshot of the actual question I am being asked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.